# Pandas Dataframe groupby and then filter based on menu or text option

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

my dataframe looks like below, and my intention is to `pandas.groupby` on the students name and find out what what activity which they did between  'english' and 'hindi'

```
 data ={'StudentId':['AAdams','AAdams','AAdams','AAdams','AAdams','AAdams',
                'BBrooks','BBrooks','BBrooks','BBrooks','BBrooks',],

'activity':['came school','english','lunch','hindi','sports','left school','came school','english','read','hindi','left school'],
'month':[11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,12,1,1]}

pd.DataFrame(data)

StudentId   activity    month
0   AAdams  came school 11
1   AAdams  english 11
2   AAdams  lunch   11
3   AAdams  hindi   11
4   AAdams  sports  12
5   AAdams  left school 12
6   BBrooks came school 12
7   BBrooks english 12
8   BBrooks read    12
9   BBrooks hindi   1
10  BBrooks left school 1
```

what i have tried so far or i know is

```
df[df.b.eq('english').groupby(df.StudentId).cumsum()].reset_index(drop=True)

or 

df.groupby('StudentId').apply(lambda x: x.loc[(x.b == 'english').idxmax():,:])
                .reset_index(drop=True)
```

then take a cut my dataframe and then i can do by below code

```
df.groupby('StudentId').head(5)
```

final dataframe or output should look like only the activities between activity=english and activity=hindi

```
    StudentId   activity    month
1   AAdams  english 11
2   AAdams  lunch   11
3   AAdams  hindi   11
7   BBrooks english 12
8   BBrooks read    12
9   BBrooks hindi   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution if first value per groups is `english` and second `hindi`.

Create boolean masks by [`DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) for first and for second need ordering from back by indexing with `[::-1]`, last chain mask by `&` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m1 = df['activity'].eq('english').astype(int).groupby(df['StudentId']).cumsum().gt(0)
m2 = df['activity'].eq('hindi').astype(int).iloc[::-1].groupby(df['StudentId']).cumsum().gt(0)

df = df[m1 & m2]
print (df)
  StudentId activity  month
1    AAdams  english     11
2    AAdams    lunch     11
3    AAdams    hindi     11
7   BBrooks  english     12
8   BBrooks     read     12
9   BBrooks    hindi      1
```

Comment: I knew you were going to help me ..... I wish to have command on python and dataframes like you ... superthanks my friend

Comment: @PuneetSinha - If not me, some another answer you get, because good question (unfortunately it is rare in these days, a lot of bad question in SO :()

Comment: yeah ... i am slowly trying to ask meaning full question so that it helps me as well as other once they came across situation like this... but i have to learn alot from you ... there is no follow button here else i would have pressed that

Comment: `df[m1 & m2]` step is failing ... with **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'bool'**

Comment: @PuneetSinha - give me a sec.

Comment: @PuneetSinha - Can you check now?

Comment: thanks for the quick response .... it worked well... but what does this `.gt(0)` do change the type to dataframe?

Comment: upvoted and marked as correct answer for the question . :)

Comment: @PuneetSinha - I convert boolean masks t o integers by `df['activity'].eq('english').astype(int)` - then get `0` for values before `english` and after `hindi`, so last compare `gt(0)`, also working `.ne(0)`

Comment: @PuneetSinha - Btw, because original code not working maybe reason is multiple values `english` or `hindi` per groups, or some these values missing per groups or change order `hindi-english` per group. So please check output is correct, if not, let me know what is group with problem (only guess problem, maybe I ma wrong)